# How to find consecutive strings in nested lists

Tags: python

```
locations_and_xy = [
    ['to', '451', '851'],
    ['Add', '1215', '697'],
    ['to', '1241', '698'],
    ['Cart', '1268', '697']
]

keywords = ['Add', 'to', 'Cart']
```

I know how to find a keyword based on a match, but how would I look for the total string `'Add to Cart'` in a nested list like above, and return a match consisting of a list of consecutive sublists that start with the consecutive keywords, in order? In other words, for the above input, the output should be:

```
[
    ['Add', '1215', '697'],
    ['to', '1241', '698'],
    ['Cart', '1268', '697'],
]
```

I'm assuming I should use `enumerate` with `re`, but not sure.

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for. Do the keywords have to be consecutive, or can they be in any order?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Comment: The return value has to be consecutive keywords. ie there are multiple 'to' yet I'm looking for 'Add' followed by 'to' then 'Cart'.

Comment: are we given that the order is keyword first?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but the first keyword in the keyword list would be the starting point for the full match

Comment: What if there's more than one full match in the input? Do you want to just take the first one?

Comment: Yes. Ideally it should return a list with all matches but the first match would be fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? To initialize the list with the first keyword

```
for row in range(len(locations_and_xy)):
    if keywords[0] in locations_and_xy[row]:
        new_locations_and_xy = locations_and_xy[row:]
```

Then we can do this

```
for i in new_locations_and_xy:
    print ([i for j in keywords if j in i])
    
[['Add', '1215', '697']]
[['to', '1241', '698']]
[['Cart', '1268', '697']]
```

**Edit**
To give an update on the comment, I have tried out a new list:

```
locations_and_xy = [
    ['to', '451', '851'],
    ['and','3','3212'],
    ['Add', '1215', '697'],
    ['Hi','1223','232'],
    ['Cart', '1268', '697'],
    ['to', '1241', '698'],
    ['Hello','3233','3']
    ]

keywords = ['Add', 'to', 'Cart']
```

This may be a better approach to getting the desired output according to the keywords if the list has many other inputs.

```
for row in range(len(locations_and_xy)):
    if keywords[0] in locations_and_xy[row]:
        new_locations_and_xy = locations_and_xy[row:]

for i in keywords:
    print ([j for j in new_locations_and_xy if i in j])

[['Add', '1215', '697']]
[['to', '1241', '698']]
[['Cart', '1268', '697']]
```

Comment: Almost. My expected output would be: ```['Add', '1215', '697']
['to', '1241', '698']
['Cart', '1268', '697']```. The entry ['to', '451', '851'] is not proceeded by 'And' and should not be included

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The output should be sequential, meaning finding the first item in the list ( in this case 'Add') and checked it followed by rest of keywords

Comment: This just gets the entire rest of the list, once it encounters the first keyword. It doesn't check for the whole sequence,  and it will get any other extraneous sublists after the matching portion, if they exist.

Comment: I have updated it @CrazyChucky, is this a better approach? I'm still learning to code in Python

Comment: You didn't change anything except how it's printed. It has the same issues. Try out some different inputs yourself, see if you get the output you expect.